# Is it possible to log directly from jvm application to Logstash?

Tags: java, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm currently building a new application where I'm about to choose logging framework. I already know that I would like to index my logs in logstash.

What I would like to do is to log directly from my application (without writing to disk) to the logstash server. *I would also like to avoid using a secondary server such as a syslog server.*

**Example scenario**

The scenario I'm imagining is that I have my top level logging framework, say hypothetically slf4j. To this framework I'd like to drop in a [Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) that would log directly into logstash over tcp.

Is there a logger with corresponding framework runnable on the JVM that is capable of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure logstash to be a syslog server and log directly to it (that's what the syslog input does).  You have to be cautious of this (or any network based logging approach) because if your network links get congested, your whole application can lock up trying to log.  Also if you restart logstash, your syslog receiver will disappear during the restart and you will lose log messages.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll wait a day or so more before I accept otherwise I'm happy with this response.